# Excel custom data validation with drop down list

Tags: excel, validation

I was wondering if it's possible to add a dropdown list while using:
Data validation:

Validation criteria
allow: Custom

I've created this formula `=OR(G11=Setup!$E$447:$E$449)` 
to validate the input, but I also need to display valid values in dropdown list ( while clicking on cell)

I can't use
Validation criteria
allow: List

because then it accepts "?" as input (probably excel treats this as a "wildcard") and I don't want that.

Please help

Comment: "it accepts "?" as input" Yes and one and multiple "`*`" also. But this is a question on how you are selling this. Many users are grumbling around that using data validation there is not a possibility for marking "I'm not sure until now" except letting the cell blank. Well, using "?" or "*" is now the possibility. Data validation is only a helper and never 100% secure. You know that you can simply paste a copied cell into a cell with data validation and so can put any value you want into that cell and killing the data validation for ever?

Comment: I completely 100% agree with you Axel :)   Just ..you know... tell it to my boss.... :)

Comment: Then only using VBA or any other possibility providing worksheet change listeners will be an option, as far as I know. Like you can use a Worksheet_Change listener for  [Ensuring That Data Validation Is Not Deleted](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/ensuring_that_data_validation_is_not_deleted/) you could also check using a Worksheet_Change listener whether somebody had violated the validation. But this needs the Excel file to be macro enabled or Excel needs an activated AddIn providing such an event listener.

Comment: Thanks for your help Axel